# Magento get $product->getFinalPrice();

Tags: magento, methods, cart

I am having issue in magento..
On my product Page when I try

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

it shows discounted Price correctly ($812)..

but when order is placed, Instead of this price, I get some other wrong price(411) ( I haven;t figured out what Price is that because I haven't set that price anywhere while adding this prodcut)

so my question is,

How can I send Correct Price (`$product->getFinalPrice();`) on Cart page..

On cart page, price is shown with 
`$item->getPrice()` which comes from qouted items

anyway I can access `$product->getFinalPrice();` and replace `$item->getPrice()`. with `$product->getFinalPrice();` on cart page ???

can anybody guide me why prices are shown so wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Check is there any other "Shopping Cart Price Rule" or "coupons" are being applied...